# How is the process to apply for Italian nationality by marriage, if you already fulfilled all the requirements?

Tags: citizenship, eu-spouses, italy

I want to ask, After fulfilling the requirements to apply for Italian nationality, how long does the process take? How long does it take since you deliver the documents until they give you the nationality?

Comment: After having submitted your application for naturalization, the  competent authorities will have to make a decision on your application within 2 years. If you don't get a response within 2 years (assuming your application was complete) then you will become an Italian citizen by default.

Comment: Sayed, could you provide a link to that? Also, is there remedy to find out the status of the application?

Comment: @Ouflak added an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having submitted your application for naturalization, the competent authorities will have to make a decision on your application within 730 days (2 years) to conclude the procedure for granting or refusing on the basis of the evaluation made as stated on the ([Article 3 of D.P.R. No.362 / 1994](http://old.asgi.it/public/parser_download/save/d.p.r.362.1994.pdf)) which says;

> ''3. Definition of the procedure.
>
> 1. As foreseen in Articles 2 and 4 of Law 7 August 1990, no. 241, the time limit for the definition of the proceedings referred to in this
>    Regulation shall be **seven hundred and thirty days**  from the date of
>    submission of the application.''

To check online the progress of your application for citizenship, a web service is available from the Department for Civil Liberties and Immigration.

Just log on to the [website of the service](https://nullaostalavoro.dlci.interno.it/Ministero/Index2), which you enter in a reserved area.

After clicking on the 'See Your Practice' link, you have to fill out the form provided by the computer system with your personal information. After completing the registration phase, the applicant must associate his / her user with the code assigned to the citizenship application (K10 and K10C).

If the application was filed for marriage, that is because the foreigner is married to an Italian citizen (for others it's different) and the applicant does'nt get a response within 730 days he/she becomes entitled to full subjective right to the acquisition of Italian citizenship, since it is impossible to reject the claim beyond 730 days pursuant to [art. 8, paragraph 2 of Law No. 91/92 on Citizenship](http://www.comune.jesi.an.it/MV/leggi/l91-92.htm).

In order to assert this right, the foreigner resorts to the ordinary judge who, after verifying the legal requirements, recognizes the right of the alien to become an Italian citizen in case the Ministry has not adopted the decree of recognition or refusal of citizenship by the terms laid down.